# Wordpress plugin ABSPATH or die

Tags: wordpress, plugins

wordpress plugin .php file  has the first line as

```
defined('ABSPATH') or die("Cannot access pages directly.");
```

i understand that this line protects php file and prevents direct access.

what to do if i want to access the file or activate it in a wordpress website. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't impact you as plugin activation use ABSPATH. It should actually be `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'my-plugin-dir/my-filename.php';`

Where *my-plugin-dir* is the server directory of your plugin, and *my-filename.php* is the file you want to load.

(I've used `include_once` in my example, but obviously if you need to load this file more than once use `include` instead)